# there is an error in xml document (2 2) xmlns='' was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, linq, serialization, xml-deserialization

The error I am getting is all over stackoverflow answered again and again, I have tried few changes in the code but not able to remove the error. here is the class I am using for serialization and deserialization. Please have a look at it.

I don't understand terms like XMLroot, XML element and namespace. So please answer accordingly, like what namespace should I give, what could be the XML root.

If u can edit it, it would be great:

```
namespace tudumo9
{

  public class data
  {
    public string project_name;
    public string note_text;
    public string tag_text;
    public DateTime start_date;
    public DateTime due_date;
    public string action;

    public  data(){}

  }
}
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <data>
    <project_name>p1</project_name>
    <tag_text>tagged</tag_text>
    <start_date>0001-01-01T00:00:00</start_date>
    <due_date>0001-01-01T00:00:00</due_date>
    <action>Action</action>
  </data>
</ArrayOfData>
```

Comment: Check the xml,please

Comment: I tried with this thing

Comment: [Serializable,XmlRoot(ElementName="data",Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance/")]

Comment: I am able to deserialize if I serialize only one object, but when I do it with a List, I get this error

Comment: With a list? What do you mean? Several `<data>` elements in the xml?

Comment: Yes several objects of class 'data'

Comment: In the XML example I have use type List<data> for serialization and deserialization, although i have created only one project for example purpose and I am getting error but instead if I use type data,there is no error

Comment: If the problem only happens when you use more than one object, then  you need to post an example with _two objects_!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace ConsoleApplication25
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ArrayOfData));
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(FILENAME);
            ArrayOfData newArrayOfData = (ArrayOfData)xs.Deserialize(reader);

        }

    }
    [XmlRoot("ArrayOfData")]
    public class ArrayOfData
    {
        [XmlElement("data")]
        public List<data> c_Data { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("data")]
    public class data
    {
        [XmlElement("project_name")]
        public string project_name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("note_text")]
        public string note_text { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("tag_text")]
        public string tag_text { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("start_date")]
        public DateTime start_date { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("due_date")]
        public DateTime due_date { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("action")]
        public string action { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: <Arrayofdata xmlns="> not expected

Comment: How using class ArrayofData with a list member of class data is different from my approach of using just a list of class data

Comment: This is the deserialize function I amusing

Comment: public static ArrayOfData load(string filename)
        {

            using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(data));
                return (ArrayOfData)xml.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                all_data = load("data.xml");

            }

Comment: Added my usual code.  Stream sometimes give issues so I normally use a textreader.